# awk: too many output files 10 record number 12

Tags: linux, file, unix, awk, sunos

Iam getting issue while trying to split the files. 
Can anyone help me with this ?

Sample content:

```
apple fruit
goa   fruit
tomato vegetable
tiger  animal
```

Script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 awk 'FNR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    {
        if(!f[$2]) { print hdr >"file" $2".htm"; f[$2] = 1 }
        print >>"file" $2".htm"
    }' samplefile.txt
```

Comment: the content i gave is just a sample . but the actual file is having more than 500 records

Comment: Is this question targeted for Linux, Solaris, or both? Solaris utilities are anemic at times. Sun managed to provide something more anemic than Posix.

Comment: SunOS PREWEB213 5.10 Generic_150400-59 sun4v sparc sun4v

Comment: The question is, Is this question targeted for Linux, Solaris, or both? Please state the platform or platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(untested since samples are not given), in case of sun o.s use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` OR `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`(please refer comments in this answer for more details too).

Seems like OP was using OLD broken `awk` where `close` function was not working of following solution, so I have suggested OP to use `xpg` awk(s), later Ed sir confirmed that too.

```
#!/bin/bash
 awk 'FNR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    {
        if($2 != prev){close(file)}
        file="file" $2 ".htm"
        if(!f[$2]) {print hdr > file; f[$2] = 1 }
        print >> file
        prev=$2
    }' samplefile.txt
```

OR try:

```
#!/bin/bash
 awk 'FNR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    {
        file="file" $2 ".htm"
        if(file!=prev){close(prev)}
        if(!f[$2]) {print hdr > file; f[$2] = 1 }
        print >> file
        prev=file
    }' samplefile.txt
```

Comment: @venky513, Could you please try my OR solution once and let me know then?

Comment: @venky513, I am pretty sure 1 of them should work, also please clarify that are you running this on linux or on Sun os?

Comment: @venky513, sun os awk is OLD awk, make sure you are running it as `nawk` or `xpg` awks try one of them?

Comment: thanks boss that solved the issue. Have got the article too  http://computer-programming-forum.com/11-awk/38890a7c11e28b05.htm   to use always nawk instead of awk

Comment: i got  a problem here the content is being written multiple times to the file for above code snippet any help?

Comment: @venky - to be clear that article is referring to Solaris only where the default awk is old, broken awk (aka `oawk`) and you should NOT use nawk as it is also pre-POSIX and missing features. On Solaris use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk (or xpg6) as it's very close to POSIX compliant.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you  Ed sir, I have added this part in my answer now.

Comment: @kvantour, sure sir, edited it now, thank you. Kindly do let me know in case anything needs to be added more here.

Comment: Using `print >filename` in awk will open the file and truncate its length down to zero, if it existed. awk would then keep the file open until the end of the program. If you do this for many files, you would run into resource limitations. This is the issue the OP had. The way out of this is by closing the files when not needed and reopening them when needed. Writing, in that  case is done with `print >> filename`.

Comment: @kvantour.IMHO, I am doing `print hdr > filename` when `$2` never came into array else I am doing `print >> filename` so I don't think so it will overwrite the existing file. I apologies if I got it wrongly, would like to request you to feel free to edit my answer for better understanding of all of  us, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably run out of FDs, use `close()` and try something like:

```
$ awk '
FNR==1 {
    hdr = $0
    next
}
{
    filename="file" $2 ".htm"
    if(!f[$2]) {
        print hdr >> filename
        f[$2] = 1
    }
    print >> filename
    close(filename)
}' file
```

Oh, TIL: *Old [Solaris] awk does not have the close command, and isn't even smart enough to give an error saying "I don't know what close means".*

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using GNU awk (which does this for you in the background) then you need to manually close any files opened as a result of input or output redirection as you go - you're manually opening them so you need to manually close them:

```
awk '
    FNR==1 { hdr = $0; next }
    $2 != prev {
        close(out)
        out = "file" $2 ".htm"
        if ( !seen[out]++ ) {
            print hdr > out
        }
        prev = $2
    }
    { print >> out }
' samplefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope by split you want to assign each field #1 to its corresponding file.
Here is one-liner awk script:

```
awk '$1 in uniqSet == 0 {uniqSet[$1]=1;system("echo "$1" >> file"$2".htm");}' input
```

#### Explanations:

`$1 in uniqSet == 0` handle only elements not dealt already, element not in uniqSet.

`uniqSet[$1]=1;` mark element in uniqSet as dealt.

`system("echo "$1" >> file"$2".htm");` Execute bash command "`echo field#1 >> filefield#2.html`"